# App crashes at startup on some emulator - why?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Our game upgrade unity version 5.6 to 2018.4. It works well on most of android devices, but on some emulator will crash at starup.

I have tried build apk with enable Unity setting "Auto Graphics API", but it still crash.

Android Emulator Information:
Emulator: ldplayer; 
Android Version: 5.1.1; 
Android Core Version: 4.0.9-android-x86; 
GL Version: OpenGL ES 3.1;

Here is logcat details please help me out in this

```
06-24 15:11:41.252: D/AudioTrack(1535): use orig AudioTrack! mIsTimed=0 transferType=0 flags=4
06-24 15:11:41.253: I/ActivityManager(1535): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=net.chinesegamer.tsm/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity bnds=[293,125][418,228] (has extras)} from uid 10027 on display 0
06-24 15:11:41.253: V/WindowManager(1535): addAppToken: AppWindowToken{139dd590 token=Token{11d81853 ActivityRecord{23087042 u0 net.chinesegamer.tsm/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t13}}} to stack=1 task=13 at 0
06-24 15:11:41.255: V/WindowManager(1535): Adding window Window{33d03ecb u0 Starting net.chinesegamer.tsm} at 3 of 6 (after Window{30d8dd17 u0 com.ldmnq.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher})
06-24 15:11:41.257: I/EmuCoreService(1764): Broadcast action = android.intent.action.TOP_ACTIVITY_CHANGED
06-24 15:11:41.259: W/BroadcastQueue(1535): Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=com.android.launcher3.action.LAUNCH flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$GmsExternalReceiver requires com.android.launcher3.permission.RECEIVE_LAUNCH_BROADCASTS due to sender com.ldmnq.launcher3 (uid 10027)
06-24 15:11:41.280: D/ld_audio_hw(1391): ld_start_output_stream, stream=0xb584a660, sampleRate =44100, channel=2, bps=16, bufSize=2048
06-24 15:11:41.295: I/ActivityManager(1535): Start proc 4080:net.chinesegamer.tsm/u0a41 for activity net.chinesegamer.tsm/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
06-24 15:11:41.305: I/art(4080): Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-24 15:11:41.305: D/libnativebridge(4080): call UnloadNativeBridge! state=1
06-24 15:11:41.370: D/EGL_adreno(1821): eglMakeCurrent: 0xb3ec5b80: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xb3f00900)
06-24 15:11:41.395: D/com.facebook.FacebookSdk(4080): getGraphApiVersion: v3.0
06-24 15:11:41.464: A/libc(4080): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xa40e2ff4 in tid 4080 (hinesegamer.tsm)
06-24 15:11:41.565: I/DEBUG(1372): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-24 15:11:41.565: I/DEBUG(1372): Build fingerprint: 'asus/android_x86/x86:5.1.1/LMY49I/8.3.19:user/release-keys'
06-24 15:11:41.565: I/DEBUG(1372): Revision: '0'
06-24 15:11:41.565: I/DEBUG(1372): ABI: 'x86'
06-24 15:11:41.565: I/DEBUG(1372): pid: 4080, tid: 4080, name: hinesegamer.tsm  >>> net.chinesegamer.tsm <<<
06-24 15:11:41.565: I/DEBUG(1372): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xa40e2ff4
06-24 15:11:41.567: I/DEBUG(1372):     eax a40e2ff4  ebx 000306a9  ecx de982203  edx 178bfbff
06-24 15:11:41.567: I/DEBUG(1372):     esi 01020800  edi b75e9c80
06-24 15:11:41.568: I/DEBUG(1372):     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000007  xss 0000007b
06-24 15:11:41.568: I/DEBUG(1372):     eip a40e0ddd  ebp bf9274d8  esp bf927390  flags 00210202
06-24 15:11:41.568: I/DEBUG(1372): backtrace:
06-24 15:11:41.568: I/DEBUG(1372):     #00 pc 00000ddd  /data/app/net.chinesegamer.tsm-1/lib/x86/libmain.so (android_cpuInit+557)
06-24 15:11:41.568: I/DEBUG(1372):     #01 pc 0002400d  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_once+173)
06-24 15:11:41.568: I/DEBUG(1372):     #02 pc 00000f4b  /data/app/net.chinesegamer.tsm-1/lib/x86/libmain.so (android_getCpuFeatures+43)
06-24 15:11:41.568: I/DEBUG(1372):     #03 pc 0000085c  /data/app/net.chinesegamer.tsm-1/lib/x86/libmain.so (Load(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jstring*)+28)
06-24 15:11:41.568: I/DEBUG(1372):     #04 pc 0041342a  /data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@net.chinesegamer.tsm-1@base.apk@classes.dex
06-24 15:11:41.639: I/DEBUG(1372): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_05
06-24 15:11:41.639: I/BootReceiver(1535): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_05 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
06-24 15:11:41.639: W/ActivityManager(1535):   Force finishing activity 1 net.chinesegamer.tsm/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
06-24 15:11:41.656: I/Zygote(1410): Process 4080 exited due to signal (11)
06-24 15:11:41.947: I/WindowManager(1535): Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{11d81853 ActivityRecord{23087042 u0 net.chinesegamer.tsm/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t13 f}} appWin=Window{33d03ecb u0 Starting net.chinesegamer.tsm} drawState=4
06-24 15:11:41.948: W/ActivityManager(1535): Exception thrown during pause
06-24 15:11:41.948: W/ActivityManager(1535): android.os.DeadObjectException
06-24 15:11:41.948: W/ActivityManager(1535):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
06-24 15:11:41.948: W/ActivityManager(1535):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
06-24 15:11:41.948: W/ActivityManager(1535):    at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:704)
06-24 15:11:41.948: W/ActivityManager(1535):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:825)
06-24 15:11:41.948: W/ActivityManager(1535):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2730)
06-24 15:11:41.948: W/ActivityManager(1535):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2587)
06-24 15:11:41.948: W/ActivityManager(1535):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2497)
06-24 15:11:41.948: W/ActivityManager(1535):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11608)
06-24 15:11:41.948: W/ActivityManager(1535):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11505)
06-24 15:11:41.948: W/ActivityManager(1535):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:12189)
06-24 15:11:41.948: W/ActivityManager(1535):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:11700)
06-24 15:11:41.948: W/ActivityManager(1535):    at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
06-24 15:11:41.949: E/lowmemorykiller(1358): Error opening /proc/4080/oom_score_adj; errno=2
06-24 15:11:41.950: W/art(1535): Long monitor contention event with owner method=void com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(com.android.server.am.ProcessRecord, android.app.ApplicationErrorReport$CrashInfo) from ActivityManagerService.java:12135 waiters=0 for 303ms
06-24 15:11:41.951: W/art(1535): Long monitor contention event with owner method=void com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(com.android.server.am.ProcessRecord, android.app.ApplicationErrorReport$CrashInfo) from ActivityManagerService.java:12135 waiters=1 for 294ms
06-24 15:11:41.951: W/System.err(1535): java.lang.Exception: denglibo show AlertDialog! title=
06-24 15:11:41.951: W/System.err(1535):     at android.app.AlertDialog.show(AlertDialog.java:112)
06-24 15:11:41.951: W/System.err(1535):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$MainHandler.handleMessage(ActivityManagerService.java:1342)
06-24 15:11:41.951: W/System.err(1535):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-24 15:11:41.951: W/System.err(1535):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-24 15:11:41.951: W/System.err(1535):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
06-24 15:11:41.951: W/System.err(1535):     at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
06-24 15:11:41.952: I/EmuCoreService(1764): Broadcast action = android.intent.action.TOP_ACTIVITY_CHANGED
06-24 15:11:41.958: I/ActivityManager(1535): Process net.chinesegamer.tsm (pid 4080) has died
06-24 15:11:41.961: E/WindowState(1535): getStack: Window{33d03ecb u0 Starting net.chinesegamer.tsm} couldn't find taskId=13 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner:9781 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedLoop:8820 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLocked:8762 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.executeAppTransition:4171 
06-24 15:11:41.961: E/WindowState(1535): getStack: Window{33d03ecb u0 Starting net.chinesegamer.tsm} couldn't find taskId=13 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:782 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.updateSurfaceWindowCrop:1284 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.setSurfaceBoundariesLocked:1459 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner:9869 
06-24 15:11:41.961: E/WindowState(1535): getStack: Window{33d03ecb u0 Starting net.chinesegamer.tsm} couldn't find taskId=13 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:782 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1286 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.updateSurfaceWindowCrop:1294 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.setSurfaceBoundariesLocked:1459 
06-24 15:11:41.961: E/WindowState(1535): getStack: Window{33d03ecb u0 Starting net.chinesegamer.tsm} couldn't find taskId=13 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:782 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayId:787 com.android.server.wm.InputMonitor.updateInputWindowsLw:294 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner:10120 
06-24 15:11:41.961: E/WindowState(1535): getStack: Window{33d03ecb u0 Starting net.chinesegamer.tsm} couldn't find taskId=13 Callers=com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.setTouchExcludeRegion:237 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.setFocusedStackFrame:4014 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner:10196 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedLoop:8820 
06-24 15:11:41.965: E/WindowState(1535): getStack: Window{33d03ecb u0 Starting net.chinesegamer.tsm} couldn't find taskId=13 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:782 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getWindowList:1354 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2788 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2689 
06-24 15:11:41.965: E/WindowState(1535): getStack: Window{33d03ecb u0 Starting net.chinesegamer.tsm} couldn't find taskId=13 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:782 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2793 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2689 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2611 
06-24 15:11:41.981: E/EGL_adreno(1821): tid 2079: eglSurfaceAttrib(1266): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
06-24 15:11:41.981: W/OpenGLRenderer(1821): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa04edd20, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
06-24 15:11:41.984: D/EGL_adreno(1821): eglMakeCurrent: 0xb3ec5b80: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xb3f00900)
06-24 15:11:42.004: I/OpenGLRenderer(1535): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-24 15:11:42.004: I/EGL_adreno(1535): eglCreateContext request GLES major-version=2
06-24 15:11:42.013: D/EGL_adreno(1535): eglCreateContext: 0x9f7e5a60: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
06-24 15:11:42.034: D/EGL_adreno(1535): eglMakeCurrent: 0x9f7e5a60: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9f578f40)
06-24 15:11:42.050: E/EGL_adreno(1535): tid 3449: eglSurfaceAttrib(1266): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
06-24 15:11:42.050: W/OpenGLRenderer(1535): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9f469620, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
06-24 15:11:42.050: D/EGL_adreno(1535): eglMakeCurrent: 0x9f7e5a60: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9f578f40)
06-24 15:11:42.297: W/ResourceType(1643): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
06-24 15:11:42.306: W/PackageManager(1643): Failure retrieving resources for com.android.ld.appstore: Resource ID #0x0
06-24 15:11:42.496: D/EGL_adreno(1821): eglMakeCurrent: 0xb3ec5b80: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xb3f00900)
06-24 15:11:42.501: D/EGL_adreno(1821): eglMakeCurrent: 0xb3ec5b80: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xb3f00900)
06-24 15:11:42.502: D/EGL_adreno(1821): eglMakeCurrent: 0xb3ec5b80: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xb3f00900)
06-24 15:11:42.503: W/OpenGLRenderer(1821): Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
06-24 15:11:42.503: D/EGL_adreno(1821): eglMakeCurrent: 0xb3ec5b80: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xb3f00900)
06-24 15:11:44.429: D/ld_audio_hw(1391): lineFun, out_standby
06-24 15:11:44.429: D/ld_audio_hw(1391): ld_close_output_stream, dev=0xb5875240, stream =0xb584a660
06-24 15:11:44.429: D/ld_audio_hw(1391): ld_close_output_stream, stream=0xb584a660,  success!
```

Comment: maybe Out of memory?

Comment: oddly why is the "c" missing? `0xa40e2ff4 in tid 4080 (hinesegamer.tsm)`